# How to identify what class an output is in R?

Tags: r, class

I literally just started computational bio that utilizes R. I'm a little confused on classes and how to identify them?

A. `wal = c(c(1, 2, 3), "string")`, what is the class of wal?
B. What is the class of `wal[[1]]`?
C.  `rus = c(list(1, 2, 3), "string")`, what is the class or rus?
D. What is the class of `rus[[1]]`?
E. What is the class of `c(wal, rus)`?
F. What is the length or `c(wal, rus)`?
G. What is the length of `c(list(wal), rus)`?
H. What is the length of `c(list(wal), rus)[[1]]`?
I. What is the length of `c(list(wal), rus)[1]`?*

Not sure how to go about these

Comment: Just editing to make it clear that this is not RStudio specific.

Answer (score 0):

For class you can just use
`class(wal)`
`typeof(wal)`

for length, you can just use

`length()`